# How to extract broken lines from image

Tags: image-processing

I have grayscale image containing noised lines. How to extract this lines?

I am trying with OpenCV's fitLine and least square methods in composition with sliding window, but it doesn't work due to high noise.

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the straight lines, you can use the Hough Transform. You will get a lot potential lines, so you will have to filter them.

However, if you want more curvy lines, I would try the path opening created by Vincent Morard.

- [IEEE paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6728734)
- The [full list of publications](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vincent_Morard/publications)

You can observe on the different images, that the "paths" can reconnect discontinuous curvy lines.

There is a [similar paper here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226729086_Efficient_Path_Openings_and_Closings).

Comment: HoughLines from OpenCV return empty array. I think it's because of noise. How can I clear it?

Comment: It's a hard problem to clean partial lines from noise, because your lines look like noise. I would use a simple threshold to clean the background noise, followed with an area opening.